# How far into legal questions do we stray?

Tags: discussion, scope

Questions like [Can I change the caps to lowercase in licenses?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13/do-i-really-need-the-long-shouting-warranty-disclaimer-in-all-caps-that-some-l) and [Do software patents for common formats (gif, mp3, h264) apply globally?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-software-patents-for-common-formats-gif-mp3-h264-apply-globally) are legal questions that impact open source software.

To what extent do we accept law questions?

Answer (score 11):

Open source (etc.) is a about copyright. It's about law. To some extent, we have to take law questions, or we can't really discuss FLOSS. But we also, I think, do not want to take law questions that aren't really specific to open source. General law questions should be directed to [Law Beta](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

I think we also shouldn't take questions that ask for legal advice such as very specific "am I following the license?" questions. Two reasons: (1) normally that's supposed to be asked to a lawyer, and might be considered practice of law; and (2) questions that specific aren't going to help any future visitors.

Specifically with the two questions I pointed out:

1. The shouting question is a general law one. It doesn't really have much to do with open source, almost all software licenses (including proprietary) read like that.
2. The patent one is also a general law question.

Comment: Discussing nuances of open source regulations, I think, is an acceptable level of risk, whereas determining legality for specific conditions would be out of scope, but you know, IANAL. (+1 I agree)

Comment: Open source as a model which happens to use licensing at the moment. If copyright went away we would still have open-source.

Comment: @ideasman42 In that hypothetical world we'd have a different scope for the site (who knows, maybe there'd even be a new legal framework for open source) — but I'm guessing that won't happen anytime soon.

Comment: Hey @derobert, I'm a [Law.SE] mod. Just wanted to chime in and say that while questions ask for legal advice are probably going to be off-topic at Law (there's been on-and-off discussion about it, but it's leaning that way, subject to a meta post I've put up earlier today) if they're **phrased** impersonally, and don't appear to ask legal advice, then we would probably be able to answer them. Legal advice, apart from possibly being a target for UPL or malpractice claims, are probably too localised.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we should accept them up to a level that can be discussed by referring to the explanatory materials for the licenses involved - the GNU GPL FAQ and the OSI FAQ come to mind.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes?

Comment: Voting on meta just means "I agree" or "I disagree"; it's different than the main site. So the downvotes just mean two people disagree; it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoters but I wouldn't be surprised if their objection has to do with the implication that we should accept questions from people who didn't read those FAQ to begin with. (Not what I think you're suggesting.)

Comment: I've been in licensing discussions with people who had read those FAQs, but either didn't understand them (and their questions would be on-topic is they write about that part of their research), or did think that the answers do not apply to their cases (likewise).